# Interface for property Action and Action<T>

Tags: c#, generics, automation

I'm trying to create an interface that has a property that might be an `Action` or an `Action<T>` as actual implementation. Some of the methods passed in don't require a parameter and some do.

After researching and trying several approaches, here is where I got to:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace InterfaceProperty
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ClassItems = new List<SomeClass>()
            {
                new SomeClass() { TitleProp = "Foo" },
                new SomeClass() { TitleProp = "Bar" }
            };

            #region Simple
            var SimpleActions = new List<SimpleAction>()
            {
                new SimpleAction() { Title = "Foo", Action = MethodWithoutParam },
                new SimpleAction() { Title = "Bar", Action = MethodWithoutParam }
            };

            foreach (var item in ClassItems)
            {
                // In "real life" this would be triggered in an event, and the parent loop would not be required.
                foreach (var simpleAction in SimpleActions)
                {
                    if (simpleAction.Title == item.TitleProp)
                    {
                        simpleAction.Action();
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region Complicated
            var ComplicatedActions = new List<IGenericAction<Action>>()
            {
                new GenericAction<Action>() { Title = "Foo", Action = MethodWithoutParam },
                new GenericAction<Action<string>>() { Title = "Bar", Action = MethodWithParam } // fails here
            };

            foreach (var item in ClassItems)
            {
                // In "real life" this would be triggered in an event, and the parent loop would not be required.
                foreach (var genericAction in ComplicatedActions)
                {
                    if (genericAction.Title == item.TitleProp)
                    {
                        genericAction.Action();
                    }
                }
            }

            #endregion

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void MethodWithoutParam()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Method without a parameter");
        }

        private static void MethodWithParam(string param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Method with parameter: {param}");
        }
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {
        public string TitleProp { get; set; }
    }

    #region Simple
    public class SimpleAction
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Action Action { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Complicated
    public interface IGenericAction<T>
    {
        string Title { get; set; }
        T Action { get; set; }
    }

    public class GenericAction<T> : IGenericAction<T>
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public T Action { get; set; }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Having to pass in the `T` parameter as either an `Action` or an `Action<T>` is the issue for creating a list of a generic type of the property Action.

The real implementation of this is used in the process of UI Automation. I am hooking an `AutomationElement`, and listening to the `WindowPattern.WindowOpening` event which is where the inner foreach loop would be triggered. The idea is, to have a predefined list of windows to listen for, and a method to call when that window was opened. Some of those methods require a parameter, and some don't- thus `Action` vs `Action<T>`.

I could really use a nudge in the right direction.

*edit:* The simple regions are included because that is the current code, and I'm providing it as a context for where I am trying to get to.

Comment: One way would use of `Delegate` instead of `Action` and `Action<T>` - then you don't need your `SimpleAction`, `IGenericAction<T>` and `GenericAction<T>`

Comment: Where do you get the argument for `Action<T>`? Unless it needs to come from the invoker of the delegate, you probably want close over it on the outside (e.g. `() => MethodWithParam("My parameter")`, which gives you `Action`, rather than `Action<string>`).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the parameter when you construct the `GenericAction`, you can also write the call to `MethodWithParam` as:

```cs
Action action = () => MethodWithParam("my parameter");
```

Then you no longer need the `T` in your `GenericAction`:

```cs
string p1 = "parameter one";
var complicatedActions = new List<IGenericAction>()
{
    new GenericAction() { Title = "Foo", Action = MethodWithoutParam },
    new GenericAction() { Title = "Bar", Action = () => MethodWithParam(p1) } 
};
```